# how to automatically restart springboot application in case of exception

Tags: java, spring-boot

is there any way I can configure my springboot application, to restart(entire container) if exception occure during execution ?

My application is spring-boot-batch application that writes into Coherence cache and if cache goes down for some reason application just halt after throwing *RequestTimeOutException* and have to manually restart.

Comment: If you're using Liunx, you can create a system service that restarts automatically when it stops. And you can stop your application when the exception is thrown.

Comment: You can programatically restart a spring boot app using the application context, see [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-restart-spring-boot-app). Just write a method that handles the restart and add it in your catch clause.

Comment: I will try that - thanks

Comment: Note that you should register shutdown hook and add your cleanups before hot refresh to prevent resource leaks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below approach by adding some dependencies :

- `spring-boot-starter-actuator`: In this mechanism the actuator exposes number of  [spring
  endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready) to check the App status, logs, get thread dumps etc.
- `spring-cloud-context`: The spring cloud context have `RestartEndpoint` which you can "autowire" into your app, and expose an API endpoint to
  restart the application

Comment: I don't have any idea about spring-cloud-context but actuator doesn't seem to help here. How would you catch the exception? There is no way that would propogate. Even if the user comes up with some hacky solution, it would be just ugly.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat Once you have sufficient info about your app health form spring boot admin, Cant you restart the app whenever required?

Comment: Yes it happen. OP would need to populate `info` or something but then another service would need to poll the data periodically which is kind of a overkill. I think a neat solution would be to directly listen for exceptions inside the service and trigger a hot refresh which won't need any other service, but that's my opinion ;)